# UnsatisfiableError while creating python environment

Tags: python, windows, dependencies, conda

I am following a python tutorial. When I am trying to create a python env I got this error.

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - mkl==2019.0=118
>     - scipy==1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1 -> numpy[version='>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2019.1,<2020.0a0'] Use "conda search  --info"
>   to see the dependencies for each package.

This is my yml file

```
name: python-cvcourse
channels:
  - michael_wild
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=0.4.1=py36_0
  - appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astor=0.7.1=py36_0
  - attrs=18.2.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - automat=0.7.0=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=2.1.4=py36_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.10.15=py36_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h74b6da3_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
  - constantly=15.1.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - cryptography=2.3.1=py36h74b6da3_0
  - cudatoolkit=9.0=1
  - cudnn=7.1.4=cuda9.0_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36_2
  - freetype=2.9.1=ha9979f8_1
  - gast=0.2.0=py36_0
  - grpcio=1.12.1=py36h1a1b453_0
  - h5py=2.8.0=py36hf7173ca_2
  - hdf5=1.8.20=hac2f561_1
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36_0
  - hyperlink=18.0.0=py36_0
  - icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.7=py36_0
  - incremental=17.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.0=118
  - ipykernel=4.9.0=py36_0
  - ipython=6.5.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
  - ipywidgets=7.4.1=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.1=py36_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py36_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_6
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36_0
  - jupyterlab=0.34.9=py36_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.13.1=py36_0
  - keras=2.2.2=0
  - keras-applications=1.0.4=py36_1
  - keras-base=2.2.2=py36_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.0.2=py36_1
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h6538335_0
  - libopencv=3.4.2=h20b85fd_0
  - libpng=1.6.34=h79bbb47_0
  - libprotobuf=3.6.0=h1a1b453_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - libtiff=4.0.9=h36446d0_2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=2.6.11=py36_0
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - matplotlib=2.2.3=py36hd159220_0
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - mkl=2019.0=118
  - mkl_fft=1.0.4=py36h1e22a9b_1
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h77b88f5_1
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
  - notebook=5.6.0=py36_0
  - numpy=1.15.1=py36ha559c80_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.1=py36h8128ebf_0
  - olefile=0.46=py36_0
  - opencv=3.4.2=py36h40b0b35_0
  - openssl=1.0.2p=hfa6e2cd_0
  - pandoc=2.2.3.2=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36_1
  - parso=0.3.1=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
  - pillow=5.2.0=py36h08bbbbd_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - prometheus_client=0.3.1=py36h28b3542_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - protobuf=3.6.0=py36he025d50_0
  - py-opencv=3.4.2=py36hc319ecb_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.4=py36h28b3542_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.2=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36_1
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36_1
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py36ha878b3d_0
  - python=3.6.6=hea74fb7_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.5=py36_0
  - pywin32=223=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - pywinpty=0.5.4=py36_0
  - pyyaml=3.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - pyzmq=17.1.2=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - qt=5.9.6=vc14h62aca36_0
  - qtconsole=4.4.1=py36_0
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36hae9bb9f_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - service_identity=17.0.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - setuptools=40.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - sip=4.19.12=py36h6538335_0
  - six=1.11.0=py36_1
  - sqlite=3.24.0=h7602738_0
  - tensorflow=1.10.0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py36_1
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hfa6e2cd_0
  - tornado=5.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
  - twisted=18.7.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - vc=14=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=3
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.4.1=py36_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - yaml=0.1.7=hc54c509_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=he025d50_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8395fce_2
  - zope=1.0=py36_1
  - zope.interface=4.5.0=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - opencv-contrib=3.3.1=py36_1
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\cvcourse_windows
```

this is my command

```
conda env create -f cvcourse_windows.yml -n cv_python
```

I tried to remove those packages but some other package conflict is showing up and I've also reinstalled conda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
name: python-cvcourse
channels:
  - michael_wild
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - absl-py=0.4.1=py36_0
  - appdirs=1.4.3=py36h28b3542_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astor=0.7.1=py36_0
  - attrs=18.2.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - automat=0.7.0=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=2.1.4=py36_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.10.15=py36_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h74b6da3_1
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
  - constantly=15.1.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - cryptography=2.3.1=py36h74b6da3_0
  - cudatoolkit=9.0=1
  - cudnn=7.1.4=cuda9.0_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36_2
  - freetype=2.9.1=ha9979f8_1
  - gast=0.2.0=py36_0
  - grpcio=1.12.1=py36h1a1b453_0
  - h5py=2.8.0=py36hf7173ca_2
  - hdf5=1.8.20=hac2f561_1
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36_0
  - hyperlink=18.0.0=py36_0
  - icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.7=py36_0
  - incremental=17.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.0=118
  - ipykernel=4.9.0=py36_0
  - ipython=6.5.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
  - ipywidgets=7.4.1=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.1=py36_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py36_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py36_6
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36_0
  - jupyterlab=0.34.9=py36_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.13.1=py36_0
  - keras=2.2.2=0
  - keras-applications=1.0.4=py36_1
  - keras-base=2.2.2=py36_0
  - keras-preprocessing=1.0.2=py36_1
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h6538335_0
  - libopencv=3.4.2=h20b85fd_0
  - libpng=1.6.34=h79bbb47_0
  - libprotobuf=3.6.0=h1a1b453_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - libtiff=4.0.9=h36446d0_2
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=2.6.11=py36_0
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - matplotlib=2.2.3=py36hd159220_0
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - mkl=2018.0.3=1
  - mkl_fft=1.0.4=py36h1e22a9b_1
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h77b88f5_1
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
  - notebook=5.6.0=py36_0
  - numpy=1.15.4=py36ha559c80_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.4=py36h8128ebf_0
  - olefile=0.46=py36_0
  - opencv=3.4.2=py36h40b0b35_0
  - openssl=1.0.2p=hfa6e2cd_0
  - pandoc=2.2.3.2=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36_1
  - parso=0.3.1=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
  - pillow=5.2.0=py36h08bbbbd_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - prometheus_client=0.3.1=py36h28b3542_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - protobuf=3.6.0=py36he025d50_0
  - py-opencv=3.4.2=py36hc319ecb_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.4=py36h28b3542_0
  - pyasn1-modules=0.2.2=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36_1
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36_1
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py36ha878b3d_0
  - python=3.6.6=hea74fb7_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.5=py36_0
  - pywin32=223=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - pywinpty=0.5.4=py36_0
  - pyyaml=3.13=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - pyzmq=17.1.2=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - qt=5.9.6=vc14h62aca36_0
  - qtconsole=4.4.1=py36_0
  - scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36hae9bb9f_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - service_identity=17.0.0=py36h28b3542_0
  - setuptools=40.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - sip=4.19.8=py36h6538335_0
  - six=1.11.0=py36_1
  - sqlite=3.24.0=h7602738_0
  - tensorflow=1.10.0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py36_1
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
  - tk=8.6.8=hfa6e2cd_0
  - tornado=5.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
  - twisted=18.7.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - vc=14=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=14.0.25123=3
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.4.1=py36_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - yaml=0.1.7=hc54c509_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=he025d50_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8395fce_2
  - zope=1.0=py36_1
  - zope.interface=4.5.0=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - opencv-contrib=3.3.1=py36_1
prefix: C:\Users\Marcial\Anaconda3\envs\cvcourse_windows
```

for the OP's error

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: - mkl==2019.0=118 - scipy==1.1.0=py36h4f6bf74_1 -> numpy[version='>=1.15.1,<2.0a0'] -> mkl[version='>=2019.1,<2020.0a0'] Use "conda search --info" to see the dependencies for each package.

it says that you have 
mkl version 2019.0 build 118
but you have a scipy-1.1.0-py36h4f6bf74_1 that requires a numpy >=1.15.1 that requires mkl >=2019.1

the solution is to upgrade your mkl to a recent or equal version to 2019.1 and older than 2020.0a0

you can use the `conda seach mkl=2019` to see all the versions for 2019

you will get other errors keep reading for the solution

---

for me, I could not generate the same problem.
every time I try building the env I get a problem related to numpy, though all its dependencies are valid but kept showing errors so I changed it to

```
  - numpy=1.15.4=py36ha559c80_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.4=py36h8128ebf_0
```

also i got an other error

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>    - qtconsole==4.4.1=py36_0 -> pyqt[version='>=5.9.2,<5.10.0a0'] -> sip[version=
>   '>=4.19.4,<=4.19.8']
>    - sip==4.19.12=py36h6538335_0

pretty much the same thing 
qtconsole-4.4.1-py36_0 requires a nested sip <4.19.8 and you have a sip 4.19.12

same solution, downgrade you sip to `sip=4.19.8=py36h6538335_0`

you will get a lot of errors keep fixing them with the same way

in the end, you will get an error with keras-base and mkl just downgrade your mkl to `mkl=2018.0.3=1`

the file is just full of miss matched dependencies, you said its a python tutorial but it looks like a troubleshooting test ?

Comment: You might want to explain what you've changed. The list is rather long and changes are hard to notice at glance. It would also probably be helpful for the asker (and future readers) to know how you arrived to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is unable to create environment in the same tutorial,
I was getting package missing in current win-64 channel for all the packages

I was able to install packages after updating Anaconda
using command: conda update conda