# UnsatisfiableError on importing environment pywin32==300 (Requested package -> Available versions)

Tags: anaconda, conda

Good day

I am getting an error while importing my environment:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package openssl conflicts for:
pywin32==300=py38h294d835_0 -> python[version='>=3.8,...
```

The yml file is as follows:

```
name: base
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _anaconda_depends=2020.07=py38_0
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py38_0
  - _tflow_select=2.3.0=eigen
  - aiohttp=3.7.4=py38h294d835_0
  - alabaster=0.7.12=py_0
  - anaconda=custom=py38_1
  - anaconda-client=1.7.2=py_0
  - anaconda-navigator=2.0.3=py38_0
  - anaconda-project=0.9.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - anyio=2.2.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - argh=0.26.2=pyh9f0ad1d_1002
  - argon2-cffi=20.1.0=py38h294d835_2
  - arrow=1.0.3=py38haa244fe_0
  - asn1crypto=1.4.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - astor=0.8.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - astroid=2.5.2=py38haa244fe_0
  - astropy=4.2.1=py38h294d835_0
  - astunparse=1.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - async-timeout=3.0.1=py_1000
  - async_generator=1.10=py_0
  - atomicwrites=1.4.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - attrs=20.3.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - autopep8=1.5.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - babel=2.9.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - backports=1.0=py_2
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py_3
  - backports.tempfile=1.0=py_0
  - backports.weakref=1.0.post1=py38h32f6830_1002
  - bcrypt=3.2.0=py38h294d835_1
  - beautifulsoup4=4.9.3=pyhb0f4dca_0
  - binaryornot=0.4.4=py_1
  - bitarray=1.9.1=py38h294d835_0
  - bkcharts=0.2=py38_0
  - black=20.8b1=py_1
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.3.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - blinker=1.4=py_1
  - blosc=1.21.0=h0e60522_0
  - bokeh=2.3.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - boto=2.49.0=py_0
  - bottleneck=1.3.2=py38h347fdf6_3
  - brotli=1.0.9=h0e60522_4
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py38h294d835_1001
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
  - ca-certificates=2020.10.14=0
  - cached-property=1.5.2=hd8ed1ab_1
  - cached_property=1.5.2=pyha770c72_1
  - certifi=2020.6.20=py38_0
  - cffi=1.14.5=py38hd8c33c5_0
  - chardet=4.0.0=py38haa244fe_1
  - charls=2.2.0=h39d44d4_0
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - cloudpickle=1.6.0=py_0
  - clyent=1.2.2=py_1
  - colorama=0.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - comtypes=1.1.9=py38haa244fe_0
  - conda=4.10.1=py38haa95532_1
  - conda-build=3.18.11=py38_1
  - conda-content-trust=0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - conda-env=2.6.0=1
  - conda-package-handling=1.7.2=py38h8934438_0
  - conda-repo-cli=1.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - conda-token=0.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - conda-verify=3.4.2=py_1
  - console_shortcut=0.1.1=4
  - contextlib2=0.6.0.post1=py_0
  - cookiecutter=1.7.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - cryptography=3.4.7=py38hd7da0ea_0
  - curl=7.76.0=hf1763fc_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py_2
  - cython=0.29.22=py38h885f38d_0
  - cytoolz=0.11.0=py38h294d835_3
  - dask=2021.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dask-core=2021.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dataclasses=0.8=pyhc8e2a94_1
  - decorator=4.4.2=py_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - diff-match-patch=20200713=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - distributed=2021.4.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - docutils=0.17=py38haa244fe_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1003
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py_1001
  - fastcache=1.1.0=py38h294d835_2
  - filelock=3.0.12=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - flake8=3.9.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - flask=1.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h546665d_1
  - fsspec=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - future=0.18.2=py38haa244fe_3
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0=h38e98db_0
  - gevent=21.1.2=py38h294d835_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h8d14728_2
  - glew=2.1.0=h39d44d4_2
  - glob2=0.7=py_0
  - gmpy2=2.1.0b1=py38hb63f22f_1
  - google-pasta=0.2.0=pyh8c360ce_0
  - greenlet=1.0.0=py38h885f38d_0
  - h5py=2.10.0=nompi_py38he6c2248_106
  - hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_h5268f04_1114
  - heapdict=1.0.1=py_0
  - html5lib=1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
  - icu=68.1=h0e60522_0
  - idna=2.10=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - imagecodecs=2021.3.31=py38hccd6b70_0
  - imageio=2.9.0=py_0
  - imagesize=1.2.0=py_0
  - importlib-metadata=3.10.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - importlib_metadata=3.10.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - inflection=0.5.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - iniconfig=1.1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - intel-openmp=2021.2.0=h57928b3_616
  - intervaltree=3.0.2=py_0
  - ipykernel=5.5.3=py38h43734a8_0
  - ipython=7.22.0=py38h43734a8_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - ipywidgets=7.6.3=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - isort=5.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=py_0
  - jdcal=1.4.1=py_0
  - jedi=0.17.2=py38haa244fe_1
  - jinja2=2.11.3=pyh44b312d_0
  - jinja2-time=0.2.0=py_2
  - joblib=1.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jpeg=9d=h8ffe710_0
  - json5=0.9.5=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py38haa244fe_6
  - jupyter-packaging=0.7.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=6.1.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_console=6.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=4.7.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - jupyter_server=1.5.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - jupyterlab=3.0.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=1.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jxrlib=1.1=h8ffe710_2
  - keras-applications=1.0.8=py_1
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keyring=23.0.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - kivy=2.0.0=py38h7600b87_1
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1=py38hbd9d945_1
  - krb5=1.17.2=hbae68bd_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.6.0=py38h294d835_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h2a16943_0
  - lerc=2.2.1=h0e60522_0
  - libaec=1.0.4=h39d44d4_1
  - libarchive=3.5.1=h8686738_1
  - libblas=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - libcblas=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - libclang=11.1.0=default_h5c34c98_0
  - libcurl=7.76.0=hf1763fc_0
  - libdeflate=1.7=h8ffe710_5
  - libiconv=1.16=he774522_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - liblief=0.10.1=ha925a31_2
  - libllvm9=9.0.1=hab3b255_3
  - libpng=1.6.37=h1d00b33_2
  - libprotobuf=3.16.0=h7755175_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=h39d44d4_3
  - libssh2=1.9.0=h680486a_6
  - libtiff=4.2.0=hc10be44_0
  - libuv=1.39.0=he774522_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h8ffe710_2
  - libxml2=2.9.10=hf5bbc77_3
  - libxslt=1.1.33=h65864e5_2
  - libzopfli=1.0.3=h0e60522_0
  - llvmlite=0.36.0=py38h57a6900_0
  - locket=0.2.0=py_2
  - lxml=4.6.3=py38h292cb97_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h8ffe710_0
  - lzo=2.10=he774522_1000
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=3.3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py38h294d835_3
  - matplotlib=3.4.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.4.1=py38heae8d8c_0
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py_1
  - menuinst=1.4.16=py38he774522_1
  - mistune=0.8.4=py38h294d835_1003
  - mkl=2020.4=hb70f87d_311
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py38h1e8a9f7_2
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0=py38h347fdf6_1
  - mkl_random=1.2.0=py38h251f6bf_1
  - mock=4.0.3=py38haa244fe_1
  - more-itertools=8.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mpc=1.1.0=h7edee0f_1009
  - mpfr=4.0.2=h62dcd97_1
  - mpir=3.0.0=he025d50_1002
  - mpmath=1.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - msgpack-python=1.0.2=py38hbd9d945_1
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - multidict=5.1.0=py38h294d835_1
  - multipledispatch=0.6.0=py_0
  - mypy_extensions=0.4.3=py38haa244fe_3
  - navigator-updater=0.2.1=py38_0
  - nbclassic=0.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbclient=0.5.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert=6.0.7=py38haa244fe_3
  - nbformat=5.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - networkx=2.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nltk=3.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nose=1.3.7=py_1006
  - notebook=6.3.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - numba=0.53.1=py38hd0eb412_0
  - numexpr=2.7.3=py38h4c96930_0
  - numpy=1.20.2=py38h09042cb_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.5=py38hc3f5095_0
  - numpydoc=1.1.0=py_1
  - olefile=0.46=pyh9f0ad1d_1
  - openjpeg=2.4.0=h48faf41_0
  - openpyxl=3.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h2bbff1b_0
  - opt_einsum=3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - packaging=20.9=pyh44b312d_0
  - pandas=1.2.3=py38h4c96930_0
  - pandoc=2.13=h8ffe710_0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py_1
  - paramiko=2.7.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - parso=0.7.0=py_0
  - partd=1.1.0=py_0
  - path=15.1.2=py38haa244fe_0
  - path.py=12.5.0=0
  - pathlib2=2.3.5=py38haa244fe_3
  - pathspec=0.8.1=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pathtools=0.1.2=py_1
  - patsy=0.5.1=py_0
  - pep8=1.7.1=py_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pillow=8.1.2=py38h9273828_1
  - pip=21.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pkginfo=1.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pluggy=0.13.1=py38haa244fe_4
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - pooch=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - powershell_shortcut=0.0.1=3
  - poyo=0.5.0=py_0
  - prometheus_client=0.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.18=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.18=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.8.0=py38h294d835_1
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - py=1.10.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - py-lief=0.10.1=py38h4b9bc1a_2
  - pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
  - pycodestyle=2.6.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pycosat=0.6.3=py38h294d835_1006
  - pycparser=2.20=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pycurl=7.43.0.6=py38hdf897c8_1
  - pydocstyle=6.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyerfa=1.7.2=py38h294d835_0
  - pyfirmata=1.1.0=py_0
  - pyflakes=2.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pygments=2.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyjwt=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pylint=2.7.2=py38haa244fe_0
  - pyls-black=0.4.6=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pyls-spyder=0.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pynacl=1.4.0=py38h31c79cd_2
  - pyodbc=4.0.30=py38h885f38d_1
  - pyopenssl=20.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pyqt=5.12.3=py38haa244fe_7
  - pyqt-impl=5.12.3=py38h885f38d_7
  - pyqt5-sip=4.19.18=py38h885f38d_7
  - pyqtchart=5.12=py38h885f38d_7
  - pyqtwebengine=5.12.1=py38h885f38d_7
  - pyreadline=2.1=py38haa244fe_1003
  - pyrsistent=0.17.3=py38h294d835_2
  - pyserial=3.4=py_2
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py38haa244fe_3
  - pytables=3.6.1=py38h153c448_3
  - pytest=6.2.3=py38haa244fe_0
  - python=3.8.3=he1778fa_2
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python-jsonrpc-server=0.4.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - python-language-server=0.36.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-libarchive-c=2.9=py38haa244fe_2
  - python-slugify=4.0.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - pytz=2021.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pywavelets=1.1.1=py38h347fdf6_3
  - pywin32=300=py38h294d835_0
  - pywin32-ctypes=0.2.0=py38haa244fe_1003
  - pywinpty=0.5.7=py38h32f6830_1
  - pyyaml=5.4.1=py38h294d835_0
  - pyzmq=22.0.3=py38h09162b1_1
  - qdarkstyle=3.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qstylizer=0.1.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qt=5.12.9=h5909a2a_4
  - qtawesome=1.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole=5.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtpy=1.9.0=py_0
  - regex=2021.4.4=py38h294d835_0
  - requests=2.25.1=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - rope=0.18.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - rsa=4.7.2=pyh44b312d_0
  - rtree=0.9.7=py38h8b54edf_1
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.80=py38h294d835_1004
  - scikit-image=0.18.1=py38h4c96930_0
  - scipy=1.6.2=py38h14eb087_0
  - sdl2=2.0.12=h0e60522_1
  - sdl2_image=2.0.5=h63225fd_0
  - sdl2_mixer=2.0.4=h6538335_0
  - sdl2_ttf=2.0.15=h4636d2b_0
  - seaborn=0.11.1=hd8ed1ab_1
  - seaborn-base=0.11.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py_0
  - setuptools=49.6.0=py38haa244fe_3
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py_1
  - singledispatch=3.6.1=pyh44b312d_0
  - sip=4.19.25=py38h885f38d_0
  - six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - smpeg2=2.0.0=h6538335_1
  - snappy=1.1.8=ha925a31_3
  - sniffio=1.2.0=py38haa244fe_1
  - snowballstemmer=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sortedcollections=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.0.1=py_1
  - sphinx=3.5.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py38_1
  - sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.2=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=1.0.3=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.4=py_0
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.2.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - spyder=5.0.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - spyder-kernels=2.0.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - sqlalchemy=1.4.6=py38h294d835_0
  - sqlite=3.35.4=h8ffe710_0
  - statsmodels=0.12.2=py38h347fdf6_0
  - sympy=1.7.1=py38haa244fe_1
  - tbb=2020.2=h2d74725_4
  - tblib=1.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorboard=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - tensorflow-base=2.3.0=eigen_py38h75a453f_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=2.4.0=pyh9656e83_0
  - terminado=0.9.4=py38haa244fe_0
  - testpath=0.4.4=py_0
  - text-unidecode=1.3=py_0
  - textdistance=4.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0=pyh5ca1d4c_0
  - three-merge=0.1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - tifffile=2021.3.31=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tinycss=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_1002
  - tk=8.6.10=h8ffe710_1
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - toolz=0.11.1=py_0
  - tornado=6.1=py38h294d835_1
  - tqdm=4.60.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - traitlets=5.0.5=py_0
  - typed-ast=1.4.2=py38h294d835_0
  - typing-extensions=3.7.4.3=0
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=py_0
  - ujson=4.0.2=py38h885f38d_0
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1=py_1
  - unidecode=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - urllib3=1.26.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.2=hb210afc_4
  - vs2015_runtime=14.28.29325=h5e1d092_4
  - watchdog=1.0.2=py38haa244fe_1
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
  - werkzeug=1.0.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - whichcraft=0.6.1=py_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1=py38haa244fe_4
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py38haa244fe_2
  - win_unicode_console=0.5=py38h32f6830_1001
  - wincertstore=0.2=py38haa244fe_1006
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.12.1=py38h294d835_3
  - xlrd=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - xlsxwriter=1.3.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xlwings=0.23.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - xlwt=1.3.0=py_1
  - xmltodict=0.12.0=py_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h62dcd97_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=he774522_0
  - yapf=0.30.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - yarl=1.6.3=py38h294d835_1
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h0e60522_0
  - zfp=0.5.5=h0e60522_5
  - zict=2.0.0=py_0
  - zipp=3.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_1010
  - zope=1.0=py38_1
  - zope.event=4.5.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - zope.interface=5.3.0=py38h294d835_0
  - zstd=1.4.9=h6255e5f_0
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.11.0
    - bs4==0.0.1
    - cachetools==4.2.1
    - cssselect==1.1.0
    - fake-useragent==0.1.11
    - feedparser==6.0.2
    - flatbuffers==1.12
    - gast==0.3.3
    - google-auth==1.27.1
    - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
    - grpcio==1.32.0
    - oauthlib==3.1.0
    - opencv-python==4.5.1.48
    - parse==1.19.0
    - protobuf==3.15.5
    - pyarduino==0.2.2
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pyee==8.1.0
    - pymysql==0.10.1
    - pyppeteer==0.2.5
    - pyquery==1.4.3
    - requests-html==0.10.0
    - scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
    - sgmllib3k==1.0.0
    - tensorflow==2.4.1
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - w3lib==1.22.0
    - websockets==8.1
    - yahoo-fin==0.8.8
```

By reading the error, and based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429159/unsatisfiableerror-while-creating-python-environment), I tried to change the version within the yml to pywin32=228=py36h68aa20f_1, but it did not fix it either.

I just did this process with the same yml two weeks ago, I do not know why is not working now (sadly I do not have access where it was restored so I could back up from there).

Comment: Try removing the build tags, i.e. the string after the second `=` sign. Which OS are you working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build tags in you environment.yml are quite strict requirements to satisfy and most often not needed. In your case, changing the yml file to

```
name: restoredEnv
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _anaconda_depends=2020.07
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0
  - _tflow_select=2.3.0=eigen
  - aiohttp=3.7.4
  - alabaster=0.7.12
  - anaconda=custom
  - anaconda-client=1.7.2
  - anaconda-navigator=2.0.3
  - anaconda-project=0.9.1
  - anyio=2.2.0
  - appdirs=1.4.4
  - argh=0.26.2
  - argon2-cffi=20.1.0
  - arrow=1.0.3
  - asn1crypto=1.4.0
  - astor=0.8.1
  - astroid=2.5.2
  - astropy=4.2.1
  - astunparse=1.6.3
  - async-timeout=3.0.1
  - async_generator=1.10
  - atomicwrites=1.4.0
  - attrs=20.3.0
  - autopep8=1.5.6
  - babel=2.9.0
  - backcall=0.2.0
  - backports=1.0
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.3
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0
  - backports.tempfile=1.0
  - backports.weakref=1.0.post1
  - bcrypt=3.2.0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.9.3
  - binaryornot=0.4.4
  - bitarray=1.9.1
  - bkcharts=0.2
  - black=20.8b1
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.3.0
  - blinker=1.4
  - blosc=1.21.0
  - bokeh=2.3.0
  - boto=2.49.0
  - bottleneck=1.3.2
  - brotli=1.0.9
  - brotlipy=0.7.0
  - bzip2=1.0.8
  - ca-certificates=2020.10.14=0
  - cached-property=1.5.2
  - cached_property=1.5.2
  - certifi=2020.6.20
  - cffi=1.14.5
  - chardet=4.0.0
  - charls=2.2.0
  - click=7.1.2
  - cloudpickle=1.6.0
  - clyent=1.2.2
  - colorama=0.4.4
  - comtypes=1.1.9
  - conda=4.10.1
  - conda-build=3.18.11
  - conda-content-trust=0.1.1
  - conda-env=2.6.0=1
  - conda-package-handling=1.7.2
  - conda-repo-cli=1.0.4
  - conda-token=0.3.0
  - conda-verify=3.4.2
  - console_shortcut=0.1.1=4
  - contextlib2=0.6.0.post1
  - cookiecutter=1.7.2
  - cryptography=3.4.7
  - curl=7.76.0
  - cycler=0.10.0
  - cython=0.29.22
  - cytoolz=0.11.0
  - dask=2021.4.0
  - dask-core=2021.4.0
  - dataclasses=0.8
  - decorator=4.4.2
  - defusedxml=0.7.1
  - diff-match-patch=20200713
  - distributed=2021.4.0
  - docutils=0.17
  - entrypoints=0.3
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1
  - fastcache=1.1.0
  - filelock=3.0.12
  - flake8=3.9.0
  - flask=1.1.2
  - freetype=2.10.4
  - fsspec=0.9.0
  - future=0.18.2
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0
  - gevent=21.1.2
  - giflib=5.2.1
  - glew=2.1.0
  - glob2=0.7
  - gmpy2=2.1.0b1
  - google-pasta=0.2.0
  - greenlet=1.0.0
  - h5py=2.10.0
  - hdf5=1.10.6
  - heapdict=1.0.1
  - html5lib=1.1
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0
  - icu=68.1
  - idna=2.10
  - imagecodecs=2021.3.31
  - imageio=2.9.0
  - imagesize=1.2.0
  - importlib-metadata=3.10.0
  - importlib_metadata=3.10.0
  - inflection=0.5.1
  - iniconfig=1.1.1
  - intel-openmp=2021.2.0
  - intervaltree=3.0.2
  - ipykernel=5.5.3
  - ipython=7.22.0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0
  - ipywidgets=7.6.3
  - isort=5.8.0
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0
  - jdcal=1.4.1
  - jedi=0.17.2
  - jinja2=2.11.3
  - jinja2-time=0.2.0
  - joblib=1.0.1
  - jpeg=9d
  - json5=0.9.5
  - jsonschema=3.2.0
  - jupyter=1.0.0
  - jupyter-packaging=0.7.12
  - jupyter_client=6.1.12
  - jupyter_console=6.4.0
  - jupyter_core=4.7.1
  - jupyter_server=1.5.1
  - jupyterlab=3.0.12
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.1.2
  - jupyterlab_server=2.4.0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=1.0.0
  - jxrlib=1.1
  - keras-applications=1.0.8
  - keras-preprocessing=1.1.2
  - keyring=23.0.1
  - kivy=2.0.0
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1
  - krb5=1.17.2
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.6.0
  - lcms2=2.12
  - lerc=2.2.1
  - libaec=1.0.4
  - libarchive=3.5.1
  - libblas=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - libcblas=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - libclang=11.1.0
  - libcurl=7.76.0
  - libdeflate=1.7
  - libiconv=1.16
  - liblapack=3.9.0=8_mkl
  - liblief=0.10.1
  - libllvm9=9.0.1
  - libpng=1.6.37
  - libprotobuf=3.16.0
  - libsodium=1.0.18
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3
  - libssh2=1.9.0
  - libtiff=4.2.0
  - libuv=1.39.0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0
  - libxml2=2.9.10
  - libxslt=1.1.33
  - libzopfli=1.0.3
  - llvmlite=0.36.0
  - locket=0.2.0
  - lxml=4.6.3
  - lz4-c=1.9.3
  - lzo=2.10
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markdown=3.3.4
  - markupsafe=1.1.1
  - matplotlib=3.4.1
  - matplotlib-base=3.4.1
  - mccabe=0.6.1
  - menuinst=1.4.16
  - mistune=0.8.4
  - mkl=2020.4
  - mkl-service=2.3.0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0
  - mkl_random=1.2.0
  - mock=4.0.3
  - more-itertools=8.7.0
  - mpc=1.1.0
  - mpfr=4.0.2
  - mpir=3.0.0
  - mpmath=1.2.1
  - msgpack-python=1.0.2
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - multidict=5.1.0
  - multipledispatch=0.6.0
  - mypy_extensions=0.4.3
  - navigator-updater=0.2.1
  - nbclassic=0.2.6
  - nbclient=0.5.3
  - nbconvert=6.0.7
  - nbformat=5.1.3
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.1
  - networkx=2.5.1
  - nltk=3.6
  - nose=1.3.7
  - notebook=6.3.0
  - numba=0.53.1
  - numexpr=2.7.3
  - numpy=1.20.2
  - numpy-base=1.18.5
  - numpydoc=1.1.0
  - olefile=0.46
  - openjpeg=2.4.0
  - openpyxl=3.0.7
  - openssl=1.1.1k
  - opt_einsum=3.3.0
  - packaging=20.9
  - pandas=1.2.3
  - pandoc=2.13
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2
  - paramiko=2.7.2
  - parso=0.7.0
  - partd=1.1.0
  - path=15.1.2
  - path.py=12.5.0=0
  - pathlib2=2.3.5
  - pathspec=0.8.1
  - pathtools=0.1.2
  - patsy=0.5.1
  - pep8=1.7.1
  - pexpect=4.8.0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5
  - pillow=8.1.2
  - pip=21.0.1
  - pkginfo=1.7.0
  - pluggy=0.13.1
  - ply=3.11
  - pooch=1.3.0
  - powershell_shortcut=0.0.1=3
  - poyo=0.5.0
  - prometheus_client=0.10.0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.18
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.18
  - psutil=5.8.0
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0
  - py=1.10.0
  - py-lief=0.10.1
  - pyasn1=0.4.8
  - pycodestyle=2.6.0
  - pycosat=0.6.3
  - pycparser=2.20
  - pycurl=7.43.0.6
  - pydocstyle=6.0.0
  - pyerfa=1.7.2
  - pyfirmata=1.1.0
  - pyflakes=2.2.0
  - pygments=2.8.1
  - pyjwt=2.1.0
  - pylint=2.7.2
  - pyls-black=0.4.6
  - pyls-spyder=0.3.2
  - pynacl=1.4.0
  - pyodbc=4.0.30
  - pyopenssl=20.0.1
  - pyparsing=2.4.7
  - pyqt=5.12.3
  - pyqt-impl=5.12.3
  - pyqt5-sip=4.19.18
  - pyqtchart=5.12
  - pyqtwebengine=5.12.1
  - pyreadline=2.1
  - pyrsistent=0.17.3
  - pyserial=3.4
  - pysocks=1.7.1
  - pytables=3.6.1
  - pytest=6.2.3
  - python=3.8.3
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1
  - python-jsonrpc-server=0.4.0
  - python-language-server=0.36.2
  - python-libarchive-c=2.9
  - python-slugify=4.0.1
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - pytz=2021.1
  - pywavelets=1.1.1
  - pywin32=300
  - pywin32-ctypes=0.2.0
  - pywinpty=0.5.7
  - pyyaml=5.4.1
  - pyzmq=22.0.3
  - qdarkstyle=3.0.2
  - qstylizer=0.1.10
  - qt=5.12.9
  - qtawesome=1.0.2
  - qtconsole=5.0.3
  - qtpy=1.9.0
  - regex=2021.4.4
  - requests=2.25.1
  - requests-oauthlib=1.3.0
  - rope=0.18.0
  - rsa=4.7.2
  - rtree=0.9.7
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.80
  - scikit-image=0.18.1
  - scipy=1.6.2
  - sdl2=2.0.12
  - sdl2_image=2.0.5
  - sdl2_mixer=2.0.4
  - sdl2_ttf=2.0.15
  - seaborn=0.11.1
  - seaborn-base=0.11.1
  - send2trash=1.5.0
  - setuptools=49.6.0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1
  - singledispatch=3.6.1
  - sip=4.19.25
  - six=1.15.0
  - smpeg2=2.0.0
  - snappy=1.1.8
  - sniffio=1.2.0
  - snowballstemmer=2.1.0
  - sortedcollections=2.1.0
  - sortedcontainers=2.3.0
  - soupsieve=2.0.1
  - sphinx=3.5.3
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0
  - sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.2
  - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2
  - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=1.0.3
  - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1
  - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3
  - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.4
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.2.4
  - spyder=5.0.0
  - spyder-kernels=2.0.1
  - sqlalchemy=1.4.6
  - sqlite=3.35.4
  - statsmodels=0.12.2
  - sympy=1.7.1
  - tbb=2020.2
  - tblib=1.7.0
  - tensorboard=2.4.1
  - tensorboard-plugin-wit=1.8.0
  - tensorflow-base=2.3.0
  - tensorflow-estimator=2.4.0
  - terminado=0.9.4
  - testpath=0.4.4
  - text-unidecode=1.3
  - textdistance=4.2.1
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0
  - three-merge=0.1.1
  - tifffile=2021.3.31
  - tinycss=0.4
  - tk=8.6.10
  - toml=0.10.2
  - toolz=0.11.1
  - tornado=6.1
  - tqdm=4.60.0
  - traitlets=5.0.5
  - typed-ast=1.4.2
  - typing-extensions=3.7.4.3=0
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3
  - ujson=4.0.2
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1
  - unidecode=1.2.0
  - urllib3=1.26.4
  - vc=14.2
  - vs2015_runtime=14.28.29325
  - watchdog=1.0.2
  - wcwidth=0.2.5
  - webencodings=0.5.1
  - werkzeug=1.0.1
  - wheel=0.36.2
  - whichcraft=0.6.1
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0
  - win_unicode_console=0.5
  - wincertstore=0.2
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.12.1
  - xlrd=2.0.1
  - xlsxwriter=1.3.8
  - xlwings=0.23.0
  - xlwt=1.3.0
  - xmltodict=0.12.0
  - xz=5.2.5
  - yaml=0.2.5
  - yapf=0.30.0
  - yarl=1.6.3
  - zeromq=4.3.4
  - zfp=0.5.5
  - zict=2.0.0
  - zipp=3.4.1
  - zlib=1.2.11
  - zope=1.0
  - zope.event=4.5.0
  - zope.interface=5.3.0
  - zstd=1.4.9
  - pip:
    - absl-py==0.11.0
    - bs4==0.0.1
    - cachetools==4.2.1
    - cssselect==1.1.0
    - fake-useragent==0.1.11
    - feedparser==6.0.2
    - flatbuffers==1.12
    - gast==0.3.3
    - google-auth==1.27.1
    - google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
    - grpcio==1.32.0
    - oauthlib==3.1.0
    - opencv-python==4.5.1.48
    - parse==1.19.0
    - protobuf==3.15.5
    - pyarduino==0.2.2
    - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
    - pyee==8.1.0
    - pymysql==0.10.1
    - pyppeteer==0.2.5
    - pyquery==1.4.3
    - requests-html==0.10.0
    - scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
    - sgmllib3k==1.0.0
    - tensorflow==2.4.1
    - termcolor==1.1.0
    - w3lib==1.22.0
    - websockets==8.1
    - yahoo-fin==0.8.8
```

makes it possible to do

conda env create -n newTestEnv --file new.yml

(tested on a windows 10 x64 machine)

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you happen to know how to avoid them before being created when exporting the env?

Comment: You can specify this option on the `conda env export`: `--no-builds           Remove build specification from dependencies` (from `conda env export --help`

Comment: Another option would be to use the `from-history` flag, which will only put the packages you have installed specifically