# Anaconda Environment not showing

Tags: anaconda, conda

**Background**

I did an import of an enviroment from an old installation as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209921/unsatisfiableerror-on-importing-environment-pywin32-300-requested-package-a) (I renamed it DefaultEnv). It was working for a couple of months, but now I have a problem, all of the sudden my Jupyter notebook instance for this environment was gone, I am only able to run it directly from the console

[image]

I noticed that base(root) version for Jupyter notebooks is 6.4.5 where DefaultEnv is 6.3.0 one, so I thought that may be the problem and tried to update it, but I got the following:

```
failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

I tried with [this solution](https://programmerah.com/solve-condas-solving-environment-failed-problem-4018/) but it didn't work, if it helps, I am pasting the conda console log.

```
(DefaultEnv) PS C:\Users\12345> conda config --set channel_priority flexible
(DefaultEnv) PS C:\Users\12345> conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - anaconda/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::astropy==4.2.1=py38h294d835_0
  - anaconda/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py38_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::bokeh==2.3.0=py38haa244fe_0
  - anaconda/win-64::bottleneck==1.3.2=py38h2a96729_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::dask==2021.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::h5py==2.10.0=nompi_py38he6c2248_106
  - conda-forge/win-64::imagecodecs==2021.3.31=py38hccd6b70_0
  - anaconda/noarch::imageio==2.9.0=py_0
  - anaconda/noarch::keras-applications==1.0.8=py_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing==1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::matplotlib==3.4.1=py38haa244fe_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::matplotlib-base==3.4.1=py38heae8d8c_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::mkl_fft==1.3.0=py38h347fdf6_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::mkl_random==1.2.0=py38h251f6bf_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::numba==0.53.1=py38h99fac5f_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::numexpr==2.7.3=py38h5d928e2_2
  - conda-forge/noarch::opt_einsum==3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::pandas==1.2.3=py38h4c96930_0
  - anaconda/win-64::patsy==0.5.1=py38_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::pyerfa==1.7.2=py38h294d835_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::pytables==3.6.1=py38h153c448_3
  - anaconda/win-64::pywavelets==1.1.1=py38he774522_2
  - conda-forge/win-64::scikit-image==0.18.1=py38h4c96930_0
  - conda-forge/win-64::scipy==1.6.2=py38he847743_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::seaborn==0.11.1=hd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::seaborn-base==0.11.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/win-64::statsmodels==0.12.2=py38h6f4d8f0_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard==2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0=pyh9656e83_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::tifffile==2021.3.31=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - anaconda/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2020.07=py38_0
failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

I tried this [solution as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully), but the message changed to:

```
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

I wouldn't mind to re create the environment, but I would like to avoid this in the future. I saw that 2 instances of the anaconda navigator existed (one for root and one for this DefaultEnv), so I think there may be something related in the libraries that got backed up in the first place.

**Question**

How could I be able to have Jupyter from the "DefaultEnv" without the need to run it from the console and how to avoid this "corruption" in my environment backup for future references?

Comment: Did you wait for flexible solve to finish? Consider using Mamba for faster solves.

Comment: I waited on both solutions around 10 mins but the command seemed to freeze. By what I was reading Mamba is another package manager, since may be problematic to install in an enterprise environment (anaconda is just emerging on where I am). I would like to stick to an Anaconda solution/approach.

Comment: Mamba runs atop Conda. It is the same package manager just implemented in C++. Also, 10 mins is nothing for Conda - people have solves that take multiple days (mainly because insisting on huge environments).